"Kubernetes API call failed" when installing fluxcd with k3s on nixos
I get the following error when tryingto install fluxcd. I can run kubectl commands just fine. I am running this on one of the control plane servers as I have installed k3s in HA mode. The error isn't very informative :-( Any ideas?
╰─ sudo flux check --pre --verbose 
 ► checking prerequisites 
✗ Kubernetes API call failed: the server could not find the requested resource

Kubectl works ok
╰─ sudo kubectl get nodes
NAME   STATUS   ROLES                       AGE   VERSION
mb     Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   57d   v1.30.0+k3s1
nas    Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   57d   v1.30.0+k3s1
pi4    Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   57d   v1.30.0+k3s1

versions in case that's relevant
╰─ sudo kubectl version
Client Version: v1.30.0+k3s1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.30.0+k3s1

